# BadRequestError while running painless script on elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am fairly new to elasticsearch and I am trying to List longest open event based on event type given the following mapping

```
mappings = {
        "properties": {
            "type": {"type": "keyword"},
            "id": {"type": "integer"},
            "state": {"type": "keyword"},
            "title": {"type": "text"},
            "body": {"type": "text"},
            "user": {"type": "keyword"},
            "event_start_date": {"type": "date"},
            "event_end_date": {"type": "date"},
            "repository": {"type": "text"},
            "repository_owner": {"type": "text"},
            "tags": {"type": "text"}
    }
}
```

and I am trying the following to get the difference between end_date and start_date

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "script": {
                        "script": "(doc['event_end_date'].date.millis - doc['event_start_date'].date.millis)/1000/86400 < 365"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

and when I try to run my search query using python elasticsearch client I get the following error

`BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'runtime error')`

And this is just the inner part of the query for which I am getting this error I do need help with the aggregate as well.

Thanks

Comment: hey @UmerF92, have you checked my answer? was it useful?

Answer (score 0):

try to replace `doc['event_end_date'].date.millis` with `doc['event_end_date'].value.millis`, and do the same also with `doc['event_start_date'].value.millis`.

Anyhow, I strongly encourage you to replace this kind of query by making the calculation at ingestion time and storing the result in a dedicated field (e.g., `duration`), that you can then check later at query time. Running queries with scripts is bad for performance